# jQuery - How to get height from child of class

Tags: jquery

I'm making a page with 2 `div` elements inside another:

```
<div id="id" class="class-name">
    <div class="child-1">

    </div>
    <div class="child-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying this jQuery but it's not working:

```
$(window).load( function() 
{
    $('.class-name').each(function() 
    {
        var height = $(this).$('.child-1').height();
        $(this).$('.child-2').css('top', -height);
    });
});
```

Don't worry about class names, I've used cryptic ones here

Comment: What's this `$(this).$('.child-2')` and this `$(this).$('.child-1')`?

Comment: Try `$('#id div').height();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's [**`find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [**`children()`**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) methods:

```
var height = $(this).find('.child-1').height();
$(this).find('.child-2').css('top', -height);
```

Or:

```
var height = $(this).children('.child-1').height();
$(this).children('.child-2').css('top', -height);
```

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne happy to help! :-) Could you please mark this as the accepted answer when you get a chance?

Comment: Was waiting for the 15 minutes to expire then completely forgot and got back to coding! Done now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write it like:

```
$(window).load( function() 
{
    $('.class-name').each(function() 
    {
        var height = $('.child-1',this).height();
        $('.child-2',this).css('top', -height);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div></div>
```

CSS :
.div1{height:100px;}
.div2{height:180px;}

```
$("#parent > div").each(function(index,element){
    var classnmae=$(element).attr("class");

    var height=$("."+classnmae).height();

});
```